# Какие команды доступны в с++ если не подключить никаких библиотек?

Tags: c++

Что можно написать на c++ "с чистого листа", не подключая никаких библиотек и не используя пространства имён? Как называется данная группа команд и где она описана? Пока что понял что в эту группу входят все простые типы (int, short и т.д.) а так же операторы.

Comment: Все что угодно. Точнее, все "библиотеки" вы можете при желании написать сами (они на С++ и написаны)

Comment: @avp При этом придется подключать библиотеки API операционной системы, нет?

Comment: Ну, библиотеки API тоже ведь на чем-то написаны.... теоретически, можно и без них обойтись....

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Приведите пример программы, которая что-то выведет на экран без применения API. Еще лучше - в файл. И, кстати, мы говорим не о DOS, где можно было писать прямо в видеопамять :) Это не сарказм - мне действительно очень интересно, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Даже чтобы работать напрямую с аппаратными прерываниями, понадобится либо библиотека, либо нестандартный синтаксис ассемблерных вставок. Так что ни под Windows, ни в нативном режиме микроконтроллера "С++ с чистого листа" не даст толком сделать что-то полезное.

Comment: При компиляции плюсовой программы и даже сишной автоматически подключается библиотека c++ или си. Без библиотек называется ассемблер.

Comment: @Harry, если не с нуля (BareMetal) начинать, то надо.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, если не хотите подключать стандартные библиотеки, скажите линкеру (в GNU) -nostarfiles -nostdlib

Comment: @Harry, вероятно, я не очень четко сформулировал свой комментарий. Я не предлагал обходиться без API. Что я имел в виду, так это то, что и API, и ядро системы, и BIOS - такие же программы. И если ограничиться базовым синтаксисом с++, сформированном в 1900-лохматом году, все это (теоретически) можно переписать с нуля на чистом с++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что можно написать на c++ "с чистого листа", не подключая никаких
>   библиотек и не используя пространства имён?

Такими делами иногда занимаются программисты встроенных систем (то, что называется embedded system programmers). Например, берут процессор ARM и без всякой ОС, без "кучи", и прямо по "голому" железу пишут программу.

> Как называется данная группа команд и где она описана?

Так явно эта группа команд наверное нигде не описана. Но понять что это за группа довольно просто. Если команда (функция) требует системного хедера, то она, скорее всего, к этой группе НЕ относится. Это идет еще со времен языка Си, когда старик Ритчи на пару со стариком Томпсоном вынесли почти весь функционал в библиотеки.

> Пока что понял что в эту группу входят все простые типы (int, short и
>   т.д.) а так же операторы.

Что за операторы такие? Это которые плюс-минус-умножить что-ли? Впрочем, неважно. В эту группу входит много чего, но теоретически эта группа не стандартизована и (теоретически) можно представить себе систему, в которой чтобы сложить два "int" приходится делать системный запрос к ОС. Так что все зависит от реализации и от целевой ОС. Существующие системы (типа GCC) сделаны именно так, что большинство требующих системных вызовов функций объявлены в системных хедерах.

Answer (score 5):

> Не ответ - просто многословный комментарий...

Что означает "без подключения библиотек"?

Многие под этим подразумевают включение заголовочных файлов. Если да - по сути все, потому что никто не мешает, например, написать

```
extern "C" void puts(const char*);

int main()
{
    puts("Hello!");
}
```

и получить работающую программу.

Без линковки рантайма? Ничего, потому что такая программа не будет даже знать, как запустить `main()`.

Поэтому надо очень точно определить, что в вашем понимании значит "*не подключая никаких библиотек*". Как только вы определите это *точно*, можно будет продолжить разговор и превратить этот комментарий в точный ответ.

Comment: Как-то нехорошо писать "не ответ" в качестве ответа, даже если вы в топе по репутации. Если вопрос плохо сформулирован, вы можете написать об этом топикстартеру или давайте его закроем. Если любопытно самому - вы можете задать свой вопрос. Давайте соблюдать правила

Comment: @tutankhamun Мне не любопытно - у меня все это в комментарии не помещается. Я-то ответ знаю... А пишу, чтоб было сраазу понятно, что точного ответа тут нет. После уточнения вопроса - запросто будет :)

Comment: main - это просто соглашение. Никто не мешает написать свой и главное линковщику подсказать

Comment: @KoVadim OK, соглашусь. А менеджер памяти? :) Кто `new` обработает?

Comment: во первых, объекты можно создавать на стеке. Во вторых - placement  new никто не отменял. Но если и с ни сложно - malloc и поехали

Comment: @KoVadim `malloc` не в меньшей мере заточен под менеджер памяти. Вы мне начали возражать (с `main`) в части "*Без линковки рантайма*", и тут это возражение не проходит - получается, без нее можно **не все**. Собственно, в этом и состояла моя мысль - что можно слишком мало, чтобы это имело смысл. Например, по сути невозможен вывод...

Comment: Тогда нужно определиться, что такое рантайм. Сама ось - это рантайм? если нет, тогда в винде можно к хипу самостоятельно обратиться и попросить себе чуточку. Вывод также можно сделать. С линуксом аналогичная ситуация. Перефразирую - рантайм не использует себя, что бы сделать себя (да, каламбур). Значит можно написать его (или минимальные части). Вывод - можно обойтись и без линковки рантайма.

Comment: @KoVadim Я понимаю под рантаймом в данном случае любые библиотеки C++. Тем более не приходится говорить о сторонних библиотеках...